# Leaking in [AVPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes]

Tags: memory-leaks, ios, avplayer

I have an instance of `AVPlayer` in my application. I use the time boundary observing feature:

```
[self setTimeObserver:[player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:watchedTimes
    queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"A: %i", [timeObserver retainCount]);
        [player removeTimeObserver:timeObserver];
        NSLog(@"B: %i", [timeObserver retainCount]);
        [self setTimeObserver:nil];
    }]];
```

The problem is that according to Instruments I am leaking some arrays and values somewhere around this code. I checked the retain count of the time-observing token returned by `AVPlayer` on places marked A and B in the sample code. At the A point the retain count is 2, at point B the retain count increases to 3 (!). Adding a local autorelease pool does not change anything. I know that retain count is not a reliable metric, but this seems to be fishy. Any ideas about why the retain count increases or about my leaks? The stack trace at the leak point looks like this:

```
   0 libSystem.B.dylib calloc
   1 libobjc.A.dylib _internal_class_createInstanceFromZone
   2 libobjc.A.dylib class_createInstance
   3 CoreFoundation __CFAllocateObject2
   4 CoreFoundation +[__NSArrayI __new::]
   5 CoreFoundation -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]
   6 CoreFoundation +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]
   7 CoreFoundation -[NSArray sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:]
   8 CoreFoundation -[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]
   9 AVFoundation -[AVPlayerOccasionalCaller initWithPlayer:times:queue:block:]
  10 AVFoundation -[AVPlayer addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:]
```

If I understand things correctly, `AVPlayerOccasionalCaller` is the “opaque” object returned by `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:`, or the time observer.

Comment: have you found a solution to this ? I leak a __NSArrayI and CMTimeAsValue Object when using this observer

Comment: No, I have switched to a different video playback trick to get rid of the time boundary watching alltogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Do not use -retainCount.

The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless.

You should call `release` exactly same number of times that you caused the object to be retained.  No less (unless you like leaks) and, certainly, no more (unless you like crashes).

See the [Memory Management Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for full details.

---

In this specific case, the retain count you are printing is entirely irrelevant. `removeTimeObserver:` is probably retaining and autoreleasing the object.  Doesn't really matter; it is an implementation detail.

When using the **Leaks** template in Instrument, note that the **Allocations** instrument is configured to record reference counts.  When you have detected a "leak", look at the list of reference count events for that object.   There will likely be a stack where some code of yours is triggering an extra retain.  If not, it might be a framework bug.